# How can my program read a string from a RES file?

Tags: delphi

I have a .RC file that is included in the project and compiles into the res file.  What I want to do is access the value associated with say "CompanyName".  Is there a way to reference it?  For instance something like

```
string st = VERSIONINFO["CompanyName"]
```

or an I totally misunderstanding it?

And I suppose as a followup, what is the proper format for a string table?

Comment: Is it really supposed to read it from a *.res* file, or should it read it form the resource embedded in the EXE or DLL?

Comment: Yes, I know the *.res* is compiled from a *.rc*, but do you then distribute that *.res* with your application, or is it linked into your program with the usual `{$R foo.res}` directive in your code?

Comment: From my understanding it is going to be distributed.  The res was added to the project using a right click on the project and adding a .rc file.

Comment: If you're really distributing the resource file separately, then my answer is *not* the solution. Please clarify what you really need. If you don't know what you need, then post a new question to ask. State only the requirements you *know*, not the ones you're just guessing about.

Comment: @Rob this works.  Yes I am unsure how to answer the question posed to me but that doesn't mean it doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To load a string from your program's string-table resources, use Delphi's [`LoadStr`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.LoadStr) function. Pass it the numeric ID of the string you wish to read. It's a wrapper for the Windows [`LoadString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647486.aspx) API function.

Delphi supports resourcestrings natively. Instead of declaring `const`, use `resourcestring`, and the string will automatically be included in a compiler-generated string table. You can refer to the string by its named identifier in your code, and the run-time library will handle the details of loading it from your program's resources. Then you don't have to call `LoadStr` or anything else. You could declare a bunch of resourcestrings in a build-generated file so it's always up to date. For example:

```
// Auto-generated; do not edit
unit Resources;
interface
resourcestring
  CompanyName = '***';
implementation
end.
```

If you want to manage the string tables yourself, refer to [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381050.aspx). For example:

```
#define IDS_COMPANYNAME 1

STRINGTABLE
BEGIN
  IDS_COMPANYNAME, "***"
END
```

To read it in your program:

```
const
  IDS_COMPANYNAME = 1;

var
  CompanyName: string;

CompanyName := LoadStr(IDS_COMPANYNAME);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
ResHandle:HRSRC;
hGlob:THandle;
thestring:AnsiString;
eu:PAnsiChar;
begin
  ResHandle:=FindResource(hInstance,'CompanyName',RT_STRING);
  hglob:=LoadResource(hInstance,ResHandle);
  eu:=LockResource(hGlob);
  theString:=eu;
  ShowMessage(thestring);
end;
```

Modify AnsiString to String if that doesn't work ;) didn't include error checking

Comment: Does that actually work? `CompanyName` isn't a string-table resource. It's one sub-component of a version-info resource. Even if it *were* a string-table resource, that's not how you load string resources.

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment to the ain below, I wanted to grab a string resource, the template I had was what I showed above.  The template isn't set in stone, the fact I need to grab a string is and _not_ version information is.

Comment: Primarily because of Rob's solution below.  I was having issues implementing it this way though I'm sure it would work in my program, just take more fiddling.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like version info resource, right? Then use [GetFileVersionInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647003%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API to read it. First two Delphi examples that google turned up:

1) [How to extract version information using the Windows API](http://www.delphidabbler.com/articles?article=20)

2) [Get EXE Version Information](http://delphi.about.com/cs/adptips2001/a/bltip0701_4.htm)

Comment: This was based of the FileVersion API and that is what it is being used for, but the program has some custom work that will make the API unsuitable. Thanks though.

Comment: The version-info API is the correct way to read version information, @Joshua. If you can't use the API, then you need to provide more details. What's so special about your program that you can't use the normal API?

Comment: It has been jury rigged to read from a string constant for the information I need.  I'm trying to move these constants to an RC file that can be edited by MSBuild.  They are version info, but not using the API.  @Rob